# Does taking information via cURL eat lots of hosting's resources?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Let's say I show some profiles randomly via cURL from page Facebook or other good site.

Would it eat lots of my hosting's resources? More than just taking information from database? Or curl just will take more time to load page, but not resources (bandwith etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using curl won't need much CPU or HDD resources, but obviously it will eat up some network bandwidth - depends on the amount of data you're reading from external site.

And obviously it will slow down your site, because the server has to wait for other servers to complete their jobs.